# Widget edit throws 500 in Magento

Tags: magento, widget, adminhtml

Hopefully you can help me out. Below is a screen shot of my Widget Instance Edit screen (CMS > Widgets > [Widget Instance Name]).

[image]

The Network tab in Developer tools shows a 500 error for all Widget instances. This also happens to newly added Widget instances. When looking at the page source, it becomes apparent that the page is incomplete and that is always cut off somewhere within the javascript, which script tag which sits in div.entry-edit.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Could you be a little bit more elaborate please?

Comment: check you magento logs

Comment: Ended up commenting lines 250 through 256 in public function getLayoutsChooser(). Not really a permanent fix, but at least the widgets are editable now.

Comment: Or if you look at your php errors you may find what's causing the 500 error, although it sounds like you've found it. You haven't given much info as to what's causing the issue...

Comment: For some reason errors are not displaying – even though developer mode is on and display_errors is set to true in index.php. I could only go off of the fact that page was truncated – which turned out to always be at the same place.
As soon as I have a chance, I will formulate an answer to the issue. For now I am at least able to work with widgets. Thanks for chipping in!